# Quando utilizar «obrigatório» ou «obrigatória»?

Tags: gênero, concordância

Deveremos escrever

> É **obrigatório** a indicação de um valor para o campo morada.

ou

> É **obrigatória** a indicação de um valor para o campo morada.

Comment: O sentido de dever refere-se à indicação, não ao valor. Indicação é um substantivo feminino, por isso neste exemplo deverá ser 'obrigatória'.

Comment: Ou *É obrigatório indicar um valor para o campo morada.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sendo *obrigatório(a)(s)* um *adjetivo*, teria que concordar em género com o substantivo. O @jorgeb e @gitgud referem isso nos seus comentários:

> O sentido de dever refere-se à indicação, não ao valor. *Indicação* é um substantivo feminino, por isso neste exemplo deverá ser 'obrigatória'.

e

> *É obrigatório indicar **um valor** para o campo morada.*

Também deve concordar com o singular ou plural:

> São obrigatórios os valores.

e

> As camas são obrigatórias.

Uns exemplos na 'vida real', [desse post num blog](http://365forte.blogs.sapo.pt/cidadaos-de-2a-368938):

> ... tais *actos* "são **obrigatórios** para os cidadãos nacionais residentes no território nacional maiores de 18 anos" ...

E incorretamente [aqui nesse outro post](http://ochavalo.blogs.sapo.pt/prison-architect-analise-895):

> *Uma cama* e *uma sanita* são **obrigatórios**, uma janela é aconselhável.

O correto é ***obrigatórias***, sendo *cama* e *sanita* ambas femininas.

Comment: `É obrigatório indicar *um valor* para o campo morada.` - esta justificação é errada. Não é por «valor» ser masculino que «obrigatório» se escreve com `o`, vejamos este contra-exemplo: `É obrigatório indicar *a data* de nascimento.`

Comment: Eu fiz uns melhoramentos menores, mas não toquei na questão substancial levantada pelo @ANeves : naquela frase o sujeito é *indicar um valor para o campo morada* e não simplesmente *valor*.

Comment: @ANeves Acho que estou entendendo - o exemplo `Um valor é obrigatório..` seria justifacada com a palavra *valor*, mas nesse caso *valor* não influencia o adejtivo, correto?

Comment: E, claro, a pergunta ainda existe: Por que obrigatório se escreve com o nesse caso? Por causa de alguma palavra implicada pelo `É`?

Comment: Mais ou menos, sim. Em "um valor é obrigatório, o outro não" o substantivo *influencia*: "um**a** ação é obrigatóri**a**, a outra não". Mas em "é obrigatório indicar um valor", o substantivo *não influencia*: "é obrigatóri**o** indicar um**a** ação". Isto causa dois pontos: 1) está errado quando escreves que há concordância de género entre o substantivo e o "obrigatório" na frase `É obrigatório indicar um valor para o campo morada.`; 2) seria interessante (mas não obrigatório) explicar porque é que nuns casos há concordância de género com o substantivo e noutros não.